Regarding the issue of updating optaplanner
The former initiator of optaplanner has joined a new team to develop a timefold. What about optaplanner? Will there be new teams joining in for continuous updates? Or do we need to transfer to Timefold? We don't want to transfer the technology stack, we just want to use optaplanner stably.
I would like to know if optaplanner will continue to update and release new stable versions?
